# Tkinter messagebox, which lists all empty variables

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, variables, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I am coding a gui, which has several varibales for entry boxes and drop-down menus. When pressing the "Calculate-Button", I want it to check if all fields are filled. If not it shall pop up a messagebox and lists the empty widgets. I am not getting how to do it...

```
    def next_button_open_results(self):
        if not self.state.varCR.get() or self.state.varTR.get() \
                or self.state.annual_distance_entry.get() or self.state.varStyle or self.state.lifetime_entry.get():
            messagebox.showinfo("Invalid configuration", "Please select:" + ???)
        else:
"CALCULATE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the empty widget names to an array and then show the messagebox if the array is not empty:

```
def next_button_open_results():
  widgets = []
  if self.state.varCR.get().strip() == '':
    widgets.append('varCR')
  if self.state.varTR.get().strip() == '':
    widgets.append('varTR')
  if self.state.varStyle.get().strip() == '':
    widgets.append('varStyle')
  if self.state.annual_distance_entry.get().strip() == '':
    widgets.append('annual_distance_entry')
  if self.state.lifetime_entry.get().strip() == '':
    widgets.append('lifetime_entry')
  if len(widgets) > 0:
    messagebox.showinfo('Invalid configuration', 'Please select: '+', '.join(widgets))
  else:
    # do whatever you want
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That just worked fine and wa so simple... :D